# Linux Serial Port in C rubbish characters after restarting pc

Tags: python, c, serial-port

I have a host and a client PC on which I'm running a serial link. 
The host is running C in CentOS, and the client is running Python script in Fedora. 
The settings are :

```
Baudrate = 115200
parity  = Parity Odd
stopbits = 2
xonxoff = False
rtscts = False
dsrdtr = False
```

host calls the serial like this:

```
rv = ioctl(SerialPortDesc, FIONREAD, &NumByte)
```

I keep getting NumByte == 4095 whenever I restart the client and I run the setup for the 1st time. 
Both sides work ok via the serial link most of the time. 
However, there is an error on the host side always when I restart the client running the Python script and try to run it against the host.

The host gets a barage of rubbish characters. The problem goes away when I run the setup the second time. Has anyone encountered something similar?

Thanks.

Comment: OK, so some chars crept in while the driver is initializing or while the baud rate is set to the default 9600 and caused serial errors.  If your serial protocol cannot handle this, can you not just flush them out or read them and ignore, on startup of your client?

Comment: I did that but the issues did not go away. Turned out to be the usb-serial converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a hardware defect in the USB-Serial converter. 
Use the ones with the FTDI chips whenever you can! Way more reliable.